# Cleveref and caption-based command - wrong references

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, cleveref

I am trying to create a caption command that highlights the first sentence and also uses the first sentence as a short caption for the table of *.
Let's call it `kaption`.
This is done using the `listofitems` package to split the caption of a figure/table/listing based on dots.
This works but in combination with cleveref, cleveref is unable to generate the correct reference and instead uses the label of the current hierarchy (eg section).

Why is cleveref unable to find the correct reference? And how can I fix this?

*Manually altering the captions is not a viable solution as my book has more than 100 images and tables, thus, I want to use a somehow automatic way.*

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{listofitems}

\newcommand*{\kaption}[1]{
  \setsepchar{.}\readlist*\pdots{#1}{
    \caption[{\pdots[1]}]
    {%
      \foreachitem\sentence\in\pdots{
      \ifnum \sentencecnt = 1
        {\textbf{\pdots[\sentencecnt].}}
      \else 
        {\pdots[\sentencecnt]\pdotssep[\sentencecnt]}
      \fi
    }}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\section{With caption}

Reference fig 1 before: \cref{fig1}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption with one sentence. And another sentence of course.}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}

Reference fig 1 after: \cref{fig1}

\section{With kaption}

Reference fig 2 before: \cref{fig2}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}
    \kaption{Caption with one sentence. And another sentence of course.}
    \label{fig2}
\end{figure}

Reference fig 2 after: \cref{fig2}

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: I do not know the details of `listofitems` but it might be that `\readlist*\pdots{#1}{` forms a group, thus hiding the `\caption` inside it from the rest of the world, and this the current "labelable" ting `\label` sees is the section.

Comment: After 10 years of writing in latex and dozens of papers, I must admit that I still have no idea...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you've encountered is not limited to `\cref`: it crops up with the basic `\ref` macro as well.

@daleif has already identified the issue: The `\readlist*\pdots{#1}{...}` material forms a group, and what's inside that group is not visible to the `\label` instruction. The only thing that LaTeX can do in this situation is to associate the argument of `\label` with the most recently incremented *visible* counter, which happens to be the `section` counter. Not good.

A **klugdy fix** would be to change

```
\newcommand*{\kaption}[1]{
  \setsepchar{.}\readlist*\pdots{#1}{
```

to

```
\newcommand*{\kaption}[1]{\refstepcounter{figure}
  \setsepchar{.}\readlist*\pdots{#1}{\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
```

If you plan to apply `\kaption` to `table` environments as well, you'll also need to create a separate macro -- called, say, `\kaptiont` -- just for tables. As I said, it's a kludge.

---

A **non-kludgy solution** is available if you are free to use LuaLaTeX to compile your document: the creation of a Lua function that modifies all instances of `\caption{First. Last.}` automatically to `\caption[First.]{\textbf{First.} Last.}`. To achieve this setup, it's necessary to assign this function to LuaTeX's `process_input_buffer` callback, so that it may act as a preprocessor on the input material, *before* TeX starts its usual processing.

Whitespace between `\caption` and its argument is allowed. If there's just one sentence in the caption, the entire caption is bolded in the body of the document. The only restrictive input requirement is that line breaks are not allowed either in the argument of `\caption{ ... }` or between `\caption` and its argument.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue,linktocpage]{hyperref} % optional
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function modify_captions ( s )
  s = s:gsub ('\\caption%s*(%b{})' , function ( x )
             -- strip off opening and closing curly braces:
             x = x:sub ( 2 , -2 ) 
             -- find location of first 'dot' followed by space:
             dot = x:find ( '%.%s' )
             if dot then
               first = x:sub ( 1 , dot )
               last  = x:sub ( dot+1 )
               return ( '\\caption[' .. first .. ']{\\textbf{' .. first .. '}' .. last ..'}' )
             else
               return ( '\\caption[' .. x .. ']{\\textbf{' .. x .. '}}' )
             end
           end )
  return ( s )
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}
% assign 'modify_captions' to the 'process_input_buffer' callback:
\AtBeginEnvironment{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback ( 
  'process_input_buffer', modify_captions, 'modify_captions' )}}
   
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\medskip\hrule

\addtocounter{figure}{5} % just for this example

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption with one sentence. And another sentence.}
    \label{figA}
\end{figure}

\noindent
Cross-references: \cref{figA}\quad\ref{figA}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and elaboration. Luckily, I am already using LuaLaTex, hence I tried the non-kludgy-solution. However, I tried to incorporate @egregs answer and adapted the lookup pattern to be "%.%s". Also I catch the case when `dot` is `nil` which may happen depending on the caption context.

Comment: @cr0 - Many thanks for letting me know that you're using LuaLaTeX. Good ideas to look for "dot-space" rather than just "dot" and to have a fall-back in case the caption does not contain "dot-space". I've modified the answer to take both of these ideas on board as well.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure that you want to do this. However, the main problem is not the wrong reference, but the fact that splitting at periods might be very dangerous.

Thus I check whether the text has a period followed by a space *and* something else. In this case the part up to the first period followed by a space is changed to be in boldface and also used for the optional argument. Otherwise everything is set in boldface (but not the optional argument).

No group is necessary, so the labels will be OK.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\kaption}{m}
 {
  % we don't want to split at every period!
  \regex_match:nnTF { .*?\.\s .+ } { #1 }
   {% we have a period followed by a space plus something else
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
    \regex_replace_once:nnN { (.*?)\.\s(.*) }
     {
      \c{caption}
      \[\1\]
      \cB\{
        \c{textbf}\cB\{\1.\cE\}\c{space}
      \2
      \cE\}
     } \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
   }
   {\caption[#1]{\textbf{#1}}}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section{Short caption}

Reference fig 1 before: \cref{fig1}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-a}
    \kaption{Caption with one sentence.}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}

Reference fig 1 after: \cref{fig1}

\section{Long caption}

Reference fig 2 before: \cref{fig2}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-a}
    \kaption{Caption with one sentence. And another sentence of course.}
    \label{fig2}
\end{figure}

Reference fig 2 after: \cref{fig2}

\section{Long caption with periods}

Reference fig 2 before: \cref{fig2}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-a}
    \kaption{Caption with $1.1$ sentence. And another sentence of course.}
    \label{fig3}
\end{figure}

Reference fig 3 after: \cref{fig3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I'd do it differently:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\kaption}{mo}{%
  \caption[#1]{\textbf{#1\IfValueT{#2}{.}}\IfValueT{#2}{ #2}}
}
```

so you can call

```
\kaption{Caption with one sentence}
\kaption{Caption with one sentence}[And another sentence of course.]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your comment on the dangers of automatically generating short-labels. I am aware that splitting at a period may produce odd labels and I already had to experience some splitting within a math expression or reference ;-) However that may be fixed manually for *some* captions. As @Micos solution is more convenient than using the `\kaption` expression (at least in my case), I selected this as an answer. Initially, I used the `\kaption` command since I had severe difficulties to redefine `\caption` itself.